# ExtJs : TypeError: this.layout.layout is not a function

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

In my J2EE web application there is a window with a form. It is showing when user clicks a button.

```
new Ext.Button({
        text : 'Assign Vehicle',
        handler : function() {
            showVehicleAssignWin();
                    }
    }
```

My showVehicleAssignWin() function is in TourPlan.js file. This is my TourPlan.js file.

```
function showVehicleAssignWin(){
assignVehicleWin.show(this);
```

}

My assignVehicleWin window is declaring in the DataEntryForms.js file.

```
var assignVehicleWin;

var assignVehicleForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
frame : true,
labelWidth : 200,
labelAlign : 'left',
// renderTo:document.body,
autoScroll : true,
// defaultType: 'displayfield',
bodyStyle : {
    "background-color" : "#000000",
    "padding" : "10px"
},
/*
 * layout : { type : 'vbox', align : 'center' }, defaults : { labelWidth :
 * 200, padding : '10 10 10 25' },
 */

items : [ {
    xtype : 'combo',
    name : 'include_type',
    fieldLabel : '00Vehicle Registration Number',
    editable : false,
}, {
    xtype : 'combo',
    name : 'include_type',
    fieldLabel : '00Device ID',
    editable : false,
}, {
    xtype : 'combo',
    name : 'include_type',
    fieldLabel : '00Default Rep',
    editable : false,
}, {
    xtype : 'combo',
    name : 'include_type',
    fieldLabel : '00Driver',
    editable : false,
}, {
    xtype : 'combo',
    name : 'include_type',
    fieldLabel : '00Assistant',
    editable : false,
}, {
    xtype : 'combo',
    name : 'include_type',
    fieldLabel : '00Porter 1',
    editable : false,
}, {
    xtype : 'combo',
    name : 'include_type',
    fieldLabel : '00Porter 2',
    editable : false,
}, {
    xtype : 'combo',
    name : 'include_type',
    fieldLabel : '00Porter 3',
    editable : false,
},

],
buttons : [ {
    text : 'Delete',
    handler : function() {

    }
}, {
    text : 'View',
    handler : function() {

    }
}, {
    text : 'New',
    handler : function() {

    }
}, {
    text : 'Exit',
    handler : function() {
        assignVehicleWin.hide();
    }
} ]
});

assignVehicleWin = new Ext.Window({
title : 'Vehicle Assigning',
layout : 'fit',
// autoScroll: true,
// y: 120,
width : 480,
height : 530,
minWidth : 480,
minHeight : 530,
resizable : false,
draggable : true,
// modal: true,
plain : true,
// bodyStyle:'padding:8px;',
// buttonAlign:'center',
closeAction : 'hide',
// floating: true,
closable : true,
items : [ assignVehicleForm ]
});
```

I have to click the button two times to show the window. And also the window is showing up but it's empty. The FireBug console says

```
TypeError: this.layout.layout is not a function
```

I am using ExtJs 3.0.

Anyone has and idea what's going on here? Please help me to correct this error.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

i have prepared one sample code for you try this. i hope it will help you.
there is no need to use Ext.namespace();.

**WindowLayout.js**

```
    
var assignVehicleWin;

var assignVehicleForm = new Ext.FormPanel({
frame : true,
labelWidth : 200,
labelAlign : 'left',
autoScroll : true,
bodyStyle : {
    "background-color" : "#000000",
    "padding" : "10px"
},
defaults : {    

},
items : [{
    fieldLabel : '00Vehicle Registration Number',

},{
    fieldLabel : '00Device ID'
},{
    fieldLabel : '00Default Rep'
}, {
    fieldLabel : '00Driver'
}, {
    fieldLabel : '00Assistant'
}, {
    fieldLabel : '00Porter 1'
}, {
    fieldLabel : '00Porter 2'
}, {
    fieldLabel : '00Porter 3'
}],
buttons : [{
    text : 'Delete',
    handler : function() {

    }
},{
    text : 'View',
    handler : function() {

    }
},{
    text : 'New',
    handler : function() {

    }
},{
    text : 'Exit',
    handler : function() {
        assignVehicleWin.hide();
    }
}]
});

assignVehicleWin = new Ext.Window({
    title : 'Vehicle Assigning',
    layout : 'fit',
    width : 480,
    height : 530,
    minWidth : 480,
    minHeight : 530,
    resizable : false,
    draggable : true,
    plain : true,
    closeAction : 'hide',
    items : assignVehicleForm
});
```

**Panel.js**

```
    Ext.onReady(function(){
var BorderEx = new Ext.Panel({
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    width : 300,
    height : 300,
    style : "margin : 10px 10px 10px 10px;", /* MARGINS config used in boxlayout Or border layout only */
    title : 'test for stackoverflow',
    monitorResize : true,
    items : [{
        xtype : 'button',
        width : 50,
        height : 50,
        text : 'Open Window',
        handler : function() {
            assignVehicleWin.show();
        }
    }]
});
```

});

NOTE: make sure this both files are registered in **index.html**

Comment: Snehal, I've tried this before and it worked fine.but what i want is i need to add showVehicleAssignWin() function to a separate file. And also i need to create assignVehicleWin() window in another separate file.

Comment: then you must have to use Ext.namespace('namespace'); where you have to create namespace and using this name space you can access that assignVehicleWin();

Comment: can you please explain it with an example? because i am new to ExtJs.Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: there is extra semicolon before the delete button please remove that may be you get your output.

Comment: Should I called **assignVehicleWin.show();** inside the OnReady() function ?

Comment: Same issue is coming.I think the problem is it's not identify the form

Comment: can is how your Ext.Button code because, i don't think the problem is in Ext.FormPanel. and Ext.OnReady() is same as ready() in jquery